# sum aggregate dataframe columns with different Shapes

Tags: python, dataframe, aggregate

I try to sum all values from groupped columns with aggregate syntax

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,  np.array([2, 5, 3])],
                   [1,  np.array([2, 5, 3])],
                   [1, np.array([2, 5, 3, 5, 3])]],
                 columns=['doc_id', 'topic_dist']
```

when I execute the code to aggregate array with different Shapes

```
def getsumcolumns(dfsource):
    grouped = dfsource.groupby('doc_id')
    aggregate = list((k, v["topic_dist"].sum()) for k, v in grouped) 
    df_results = pd.DataFrame(aggregate, columns=['doc_id','topic_dist'])
    print(df_results)
    return df_results
```

**I have error messge**

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (5,)
```

**expected values**

```
 doc_id  topic_dist
0       1  [6, 15, 9, 5, 3]
```

any ideas to get the sum of this columns?

Comment: What does `dfexcel == df2` show you?

Comment: doc_id  topic_dist
0    True       False
1    True       False
2    True       False

Comment: That seems to indicate that `topic_dist` is not the same between the two - You should include the output of `df2.to_records()` and `dfexcel.to_records()` in your question so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I update my questions thanks @Mortz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the `Series` of lists into a two-dimensional array / dataframe type before applying the sum

```py
for k, v in df2.groupby('doc_id'):
    print(k, v['topic_dist'].apply(pd.Series).sum().to_list(), sep='\t')
```

**Output**

```
1       [6.0, 15.0, 9.0, 5.0, 3.0]
```